# ”maatwebsite/excel 3.1“ how to filter the excel's title when import & export the excel

Tags: excel, laravel, import, export

i want to import the excel to mysql 
this is my excel format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Vae.png)

but i find i cant filter this excel‘s title "name" && "id_number"
this is my first to use "maatwebsite/excel" 3.1
i dont kown how to use

Please help me
thanks
this is my code

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Person;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class PersonImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Person([
            'name' => $row[0],
            'id_number' => $row[1],
            'status' => 1
        ]);
    }

}
```

this is my controller function

```
 $import = new PersonImport;
 $result =  Excel::import($import, $request->file('file'));
```

Comment: you should use heading row overrides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the WithHeadingRow

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html#heading-row

Your code would be:

```php
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Person;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class PersonImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Person([
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'id_number' => $row['id_number'],
            'status' => 1
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: but i don't need the title this way i try .